# Rewrite url while using mod_proxy

Tags: mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have a nodejs app running on `:8085` and I have mapped it to the root domain using

```
ProxyPass /about-us !
ProxyPass /app1 !
ProxyPass / http://test.example.com:8085/
ProxyPassReverse / http://test.example.com:8085/

#The part below doesn't seem to be working
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://test.example.com:8888/%1? [P]
```

What I want to happen is whenever the url contains `_escaped_fragment=`, the request should go to port `:8888` where my phantomjs server is running. But the url isn't being rewritten.

Comment: You have to reverse the order. First the exception, then the more general rule.

Comment: swapping the blocks didn't help :(